# python dictionary iteritems() and keys() synchronized behavior

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.x

Does `iteritems()` and `keys()` always return the keys (and values in the case of `iteritems`) of the python dictionary in the same order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This is [guaranteed by the specification](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) during the same process invocation as long as the dictionary is not modified.

> If `items()`, `keys()`, `values()`, `iteritems()`, `iterkeys()`, and `itervalues()` are called with no intervening modifications to the dictionary, the lists will directly correspond.